# Hidden value from Input not working with VUE JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hidden value from vue not working.

The v-model of the one input its not working.

```
<template>
  <form class="form-inline" type="POST" @submit.prevent="insertComment" role="form">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="text" v-model="newcomment.text" placeholder="Your comments" />
      <input type="text" name="post_id" v-model="newcomment.post_id" value="@{{items.id}}" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Enviar">
    </div>
  </form>
</template>
```

`v-model="newcomment.post_id"` value is `null`.

How to fix this?

Comment: Show the component code? I'm guessing it's because you're also trying to set the value `value="@{{items.id}}"`, it's probably interfering with `v-model`. The default value of the input should be set in the component `data`

Comment: I want to pass the items.id to model data

Comment: @EricGuan i dont know how to fix this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume that you using  using vue 2, and that what u asking basically boils down to **default value for input**.

1. Interpolation inside attributes has been removed in vuejs 2. so `value="@{{items.id}}"` is not a legal statement.
2. `v-model` inherently passing `:value` already. so passing it **again** with
   `value="@{{items.id}}"`  might cause unexpected behaviors.  [this aspect of v-model mechanics
   of `v-model` is documented in vue.js documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events).

   so, as stated, `v-model` is just syntactic sugar for:

`<input v-bind:value="something" v-on:input="something =$event.target.value">`

Please see the pattern that you should use to achieve default value for input:

```
<template>
  <form class="form-inline" type="POST" @submit.prevent="insertComment" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input  v-model="newcomment.post_id"/>
    </div>
    
  </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      newcomment: {
        post_id: 'this is default value'
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<template>
  <form class="form-inline" type="POST" @submit.prevent="insertComment" role="form">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="text" v-model="newcomment.text" placeholder="Your comments" />
      <input type="text" name="post_id" v-model="newcomment.post_id"  />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Enviar">
    </div>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
        newcomment.post_id:  _this.items.id
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

---

v-model and :value both are same.